# How to stop scroling after confirming input

Tags: javascript, css, input, scroll, focus

I'm trying to embed a live stream (Microsoft moving image).
The problem is that after each chat input the website start scrolling so that the chat input field is in the horizontal center of the screen.

https://doc.movingimage.com/display/WM/Embedding+a+Webcast+in+another+web+page [the embedding code][1]

I simply tried to use the provided code, but even with this the scrolling happens.... (you can simply recreating by posting a couple of `<br>` before and after the embedding code and posting a message by confirming with enter).

Any one has an idea how I stop the scrolling after each input?

P.S. you don't need to input a real email in order to chat it`s just a demo :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a you want certain elements to be “fixed” in place. Check out ‘position: fixed’ or ‘position: absolute’ with heigh constraints.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

You might want to keep either your chat container or the video in the same place. Without more context it’s hard to help beyond this, but let me know if that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks :) . If i use fixed that works. But i dont achive the result that i wanted. I simply want that the browser sotps centering on the input field after i hint enter when entering a chat message. Not to fix the hole stream to a specific part of my screen. Absolut dosent work i stopping the centering